# assign sld to Openlayers 3 TileWMS

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, sld

Based on this: [Apply an SLD saved on Geoserver to OpenLayers 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121930/apply-an-sld-saved-on-geoserver-to-openlayers-3) I try to set a SLD in the params of a TileWMS. The SLD is saved on Geoserver, but everything i tried failed. 
The strange thing about it is, if I define the style in a normal GetMap request it works.

My main goal is that the user can decide in which style the layer should be styled with something like that:

```
WMS_source.updateParams({'STYLES':'name_of_style'});
```

Comment: sorry, just got it to work. My mistake was, that I missed the workspace in my url of the wms...